# Did Spring removed spring-security.xsd without any version from http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/?

Tags: spring, spring-security, xsd-validation

We started seeing an issue with one of our application, with error trace as below.

"org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not xsd:schema."

with caused by stack-trace as:

"Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd"](http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd%22)

While there was no change deployed at config/code/infra level. spring-security.xsd was declared as below in xml file, which have been running this way since years and all of sudden services failed to start with above error.

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd

While going to location http://www.springframework.org/schema/security, we see there is no spring-security.xsd exist without version and we had fix this by updating URL to versioned one. But we are not sure why this issue started to occur suddenly today without any applcaition change, Did spring removed spring-security.xsd from http://www.springframework.org/schema/security or any other thing we are missing ? If yes it might me impacting any such application accessing non-version security xsd via url.

Note: If we check for other modules like mvc, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/ like we can non-versioned xsd also exist http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd along with versions. Can see the security module was updated on 20thFeb2023 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/ but looking for any notification/announcement regarding same to discontinue/remove non-version spring-security xsd. Also can see the 19th Feb snapshot of archive has this xsd https://web.archive.org/web/20230218090058/http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/

Comment: It shouldn't load it from that location in the first place but rather from the jar it ships in. So there is something else that is wrong with your setup.

Comment: Thanks for responding, okay so yes ideally it would be better to use it with classpath probably, my question was it was already running code this way from many years & spring has kept this xsd at url which looks to be removed on 20th feb , why would they have done this ?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with early versions of Spring Security 5.2 where it's schemas packaged missed the HTTP version. Update your Spring Security version or update your XML to declare HTTPS version  https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd

Then it will load from the JAR in your application properly.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/7623

Comment: Thanks Nathan, yes we fixed by using version xsd as mentioned, was looking forward to know the root cause why spring removed it suddenly.

Comment: Well, I couldn't comment on the original post as I don't have enough points but @M. Deinum is right, it should have been loading from the jar. The only reason it didn't was that spring.shcemas in the spring-security project was missing that schema for a few releases and so it tried to pull it from the website instead. The whole point is to make it so that a later website change (the spring project could change owners suddenly and be moved to whole new domain for example) wouldn't break things. It was just a bug in the version you were using.